# How do I create a broadcast message to all logged in users in Skyve?

Tags: skyve

I have a job that runs and updates user's preference details and I want to notify all the currently logged in users when the job completes so that they're aware of the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXT library provides a `EXT.push()` method where you don't have access to a webContext (e.g. from within an ServerSideAction class).

If you want the message to be broadcast, rather than to 1 specific user, then just use the method without specifying the user, e.g.

`EXT.push(new PushMessage().growl(MessageSeverity.info, "Preference details have been updated"));`

Alternatively, if you want the message just for one user, then include the user in the chain as follows:
`EXT.push(new PushMessage().user(user).growl(MessageSeverity.info, "Your preference details have been updated"));`